# 'The specified value is not convertible to type ReleaseStartMetadata.' message displayed while trigger VSTS release API using powershell

Tags: api, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to invoke VSTS release API using powershell but below error message displayed. When i run the api in postman then it is working fine.

> Invoke-RestMethod :
>   {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402903: The specified
>   value is not convertible to type ReleaseStartMetadata. Make sure it is
>   convertible to type ReleaseStartMetadata and try 
>   again.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data","typeKey":"InvalidRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
>   At C:\Users\Raj.Negi\Desktop\PowerShell\TriggerVSTSrelease.ps1:35
>   char:11
>   + $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $params -Hea ...
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
>   Unable to locate Release Definition Id 860 At
>   C:\Users\Raj.Negi\Desktop\PowerShell\TriggerVSTSrelease.ps1:40 char:6
>   +      throw "Unable to locate Release Definition Id $($definitionId)"
>   +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to locat...finition Id 860:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to locate Release Definition Id 860

Powershell Code :

```
Param(
   [string]$vstsAccount = "demo",
   [string]$projectName = "Enterprise",
   [string]$definitionId = "860",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$personalAccessToken  = "asdfasdf"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)")) }

# Construct the REST URL
$uri = "https://$vstsAccount.vsrm.visualstudio.com/$projectName/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.3"

Write-Host "Uri :" $uri

$params = 
'[
{
    "definitionId": 860,
    "description": "Create Release from postman.",
    "artifacts": [],
    "isDraft": false,
    "reason": "Demo purpose",
    "manualEnvironments": null,
    "environmentsMetadata": null, 
    "properties": null, 
    "variables": null
}
]'

Write-Host " Json Body :" $params

# Invoke the REST call and capture the results
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $params -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Verbose -Debug

# This call should only provide a single result; Capture the Build ID from the result
if ($result.count -eq 0)
{
     throw "Unable to locate Release Definition Id $($definitionId)"
}
else
{
    Write-host "Success!!!"
}
```

Postman Request :

```
{
    "definitionId": 860,
    "description": "Create Release from postman.",
    "artifacts": [],
    "isDraft": false,
    "reason": "Demo purpose",
    "manualEnvironments": null
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the request you're sending with Postman?

Comment: Added postman request.

Comment: Without searching all over the internet, why are you wrapping your body in `[ ]` as well as `{ }`?

Comment: Does using a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6#here-strings) and updating the api version like @Shayki mentioned give you the desired results? Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216277/tfs-api-create-release-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeed to trigger release with minor changes:

1) The beginning of the URL is different and the preview is `8`

```
$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$vstsAccount/$projectName/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.8"
```

2) The JSON body is in this format:

```
$params = 
@"
{
    "definitionId": 860,
    "description": "Create Release from PowerShell",
    "artifacts": [],
    "isDraft": false,
    "reason": "Demo purpose",
    "manualEnvironments": null,
    "environmentsMetadata": null, 
    "properties": null, 
    "variables": null
}
"@
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that the **body** defined in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#request-body) is the same as **ReleaseStartMetadata**. Try to specify the missing properties in your powershell `$params` variable

> `$params = 
>   '[
>   {
>       "definitionId": 860,
>       "description": "Trigger release from powershell.",
>       "artifacts": [],
>       "isDraft": false,
>       "reason": "Demo purpose",`
>   
>       **`"manualEnvironments": null,
>       "environmentsMetadata": null, 
>       "properties": null, 
>       "variables": null`**
>   
>   `}
>   ]'`

### Body

[image]

### ReleaseStartMetadata

[image]

Comment: thnks for answer but same error. updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Real solution is setting the `Depth` parameter of ConvertTo-Json cmdlet so that you use the full representation of the object in JSON. Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2017/04/06/vs402903-the-specified-value-is-not-convertible-to-type-releasedefinition-make-sure-it-is-convertible-to-type-releasedefinition-and-try-again/